# Meson Install failed for Libcamera build

Tags: linux, ubuntu, build, ninja, meson-build

I'm having some trouble build `libcamera` into my Ubuntu machine.
I'm following the [instructions](https://github.com/kbingham/libcamera), but it fails during `ninja -C build install`

This is the error:

```
felipe# ninja -C build install
ninja: Entering directory `build'
[1/2] Installing files.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/mesonbuild/mesonmain.py", line 129, in run
    return options.run_func(options)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/mesonbuild/minstall.py", line 514, in run
    installer.do_install(datafilename)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/mesonbuild/minstall.py", line 330, in do_install
    d = pickle.load(ifile)
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'OctalInt' on <module 'mesonbuild.coredata' from '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/mesonbuild/coredata.py'>
FAILED: meson-install 
/home/felipe/.local/bin/meson install --no-rebuild
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

Not sure how to follow from here.
I've tried updating everything, even removing and reinstalling `meson` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

It looks as possible that you face what is described in the end of instructions (your [link](https://github.com/kbingham/libcamera)) - you have system and local meson installations of different versions, so

> If a version of meson which is different from the system-wide version
> is already installed, uninstall that meson using pip3, and install
> again without the --user argument.

And finally (while writing) I found confirmation of my suspicion [here](https://github.com/mesonbuild/meson/issues/8425).